# Flask POST not retrieved by request.json

Tags: python, json, post, flask

I would like to create a REST-Api using Flask.
As a "frame" I found this [Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) which seemed to be really good about creating a REST-API using Flask and it also seems to be easy...

I have this function:

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')
```

But when I try to post data using SOAPUI or HTTPRequester (in Firefox) I always get a server error 500

My application/json data looks like this:

```
{
 'username' : 'John',
 'password' : '1234'
}
```

And I checked that in both tols it is sent as application/json.

So I inserted the following before the request.json:

```
if not request.json:
    abort(400)
```

And now it aborts with code 400 - so it seems not to be a json object, right?

Then I inserted the following lines:

```
test = request
print test.data
```

Then I retrieve this in the console which looks tome like JSON:

```
{
    'username' : 'John',
    'password' : '1234'

    }
```

I know I could transform that into a dictionay using this:

```
dict = ast.literal_eval(test.data)
```

But I would like to use the standard functonality from flask.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Why not use the `json` library? `my_dict_data = json.loads(request.data)`

Comment: You might want to try using " instead of ' in the REST client. I remember Postman not accepting ' for application/json.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your HTML headers sent by your client (JS or anything else). `Content-Type` should be `application/json`. And use `request.get_json()`.

**UPD:** also you can try to use `request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)`. And flask code for this method is very simple, you can debug it putting breakpoints or writing to log in it for better understanding what happens.

Answer (score -1):

So this is now what really worked for me:

```
if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    jdata = json.loads(request.data)

    if not request.json:
        abort(400)

    username = jdata.get('username')
    password = jdata.get('password')
```

I also tried to post the JSON with cURL - always make sure to have a `'` for the outbound string and `"` for the inner keys like this:

```
'{"username" : "John", "password" : "1234"}'
```

Python doesn't care which way they are for a dictionary but JSON does...